# Errors when creating set

Tags: c++, set

I would like to know why i am unable to create a set.
I am getting the following error

Here is my codes.

Point.cpp My Point class

```
bool Point::operator<(const Point& p2)const {
return p21.length < p2.getScalarValue();
}

bool Point::operator>(const Point p2) {
bool result;
result = length > p2.getScalarValue();
return result;
```

}

and in my main.cpp

```
set<Point> s_p2;
Point tempp2;
s_p2.insert(tempp2);
```

After following your inputs, i have edited the codes and i have the following error

Point.cpp:56:46: error: passing ‘const Point’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘double Point::getScalarValue()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Is this because i got two comparing statements ?

Comment: What's the `true` supposed to represent? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert

Comment: Try this one: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/insert/

Comment: @chris I thought, i need to give a value for the comparing

Comment: @user1571494, The `operator<` you provide is meant to take care of all of the comparing.

Comment: @chris i have editing according to the experts input but i now getting a different error. Can u assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it. I need to make my get getScalarValue() const also.
as it only returns the value.

It complies and runs without error.

Answer (score 5):

There is no [std::set::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) overload that takes a bool as second paramater. You can insert like this:

```
s_p2.insert(tempp2);
```

Your `operator<` could be improved too, by making it a `const` method, taking a `const` reference parameter:

```
class Point {
  // as before
  bool operator<(const Point& p) const;
};  //                            ^ here, const method

bool Point::operator<(const Point& p2) const {
  return length < p2.length;
}
```

You could also choose to make it a non-member function:

```
bool operator<(const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) {
  return lhs.getScalarValue() < rhs.getScalarValue();
}
```

This has the advantage of being completely symmetric to LHS and RHS. This matters if you have implicit conversions to `Point` or typed derived from `Point`.

Comment: After following your idea i am getting this error/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_function.h:236:22: error: passing ‘const Point2D’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘bool Point2D::operator<(Point2D)’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Comment: @user1571494, It's suggested in the answer (and the other one) to make it a `const` member.

Comment: @user1571494 you need to make the comparison operator a const method, or a non-member function. It doesn't make sense for a comparison to change its arguments.

Answer (score 4):

- Insert only takes 1 parameters (in your case)
- `Point::operator<` should be a const member function and take a const Point as a parameter (possibly a const reference)
- You don't need to specify `less<Point>` (in your case)

Comment: After following your idea, i now getting this error /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_function.h:236:22: error: passing ‘const Point2D’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘bool Point2D::operator<(Point2D)’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Comment: is `getScalarValue()` a const member function ?

Comment: Have a look on the edited codes and the error. Y i cant pass two agruments

Comment: the comparison operator is either a non member function `bool operator<(const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs);` or a member function `class Point { bool operator<(const POint& rhs) const ; }` Also you can't implement a default set with a `>` comparison. It can only be '<'.

Comment: ok But if i follow as memeber function and have only one argumentm i get this error Point.cpp:56:46: error: passing ‘const Point2D’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘double Point::getScalarValue()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Comment: have you made getScalarValue() a const member function ? Beside if you do it as a member function, you can directly compare members even though they are private, so you don't really have to call getScallarValue()

Answer (score 3):

The signature of `insert` is one of:

```
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( const value_type& value );
(1) 
std::pair<iterator, bool> insert( value_type&& value );
(2) (since C++11)
iterator insert( iterator hint, const value_type& value );
iterator insert( const_iterator hint, const value_type& value );
(3) (until C++11) 
(since C++11)
iterator insert( const_iterator hint, value_type&& value );
(4) (since C++11)
template< class InputIt >
void insert( InputIt first, InputIt last );
(5) 
void insert( std::initializer_list<value_type> ilist );
(6) (since C++11)
```

Read `value_type` as `Point`. You're calling it with `Point, bool`. None of these match. What do you think the `true` parameter does?

Just call it as

```
s_p2.insert(tempp2);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `insert()` in `set` which takes an element and `bool`. Just do `s_p2.insert(tempp2);`.